# Persisting time ojects as entities instead of value types?

Tags: java, hibernate, wrapper, factory, jodatime

I'm using Joda Time DateTime to handle date and time. I persist objects of this kind using the class PersistentDateTime bundled in the [jodatime hibernate code](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/index.html).

I have large collections of DateTime objects, and I currently persist them in the following way (an excerpt of an  hibernate mapping file follows):

```
<set name="validInstants" sort="natural">
     <key column="myobject_id"/>
     <element column="date" type="myproject.utilities.hibernate.types.PersistentDateTime"/>
 </set>
```

Doing so, i.e. storing DateTimes as **value types**, I get many duplicate elements in the table validInstants, hundreds of thousands of them. **I'd like to avoid this and have in the validInstants table the DateTimes needed, stored once per value**. How can I achieve this?

As far as I know (I'm and Hibernate beginner) the only way to achieve this is by creating a class that wraps a DateTime and maps it as an entity, plus creating a factory which returns always the same DateTime-wrapper when asking for the same Date. 
Is this the best way to do what I want? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the relationship between the entity being stored here and the `validInstants` set? Does the entity "own" the validInstants? Does a member of `validInstants` have any use or life outside of the entity it is declared as a part of?

If not, then I don't think it makes any sense to treat a non-entity as an entity (which would be what you'd be doing if you "creating a class that wraps a DateTime and maps it as an entity").

I would not worry about having many duplicate elements in the table storing these dates, unless it's proven to be a large problem. With indexing on the `myobject_id` column, these lookups should be fast enough.

Comment: A validInstants member, i.e. a DateTime, can be used by many other objects, as, if I refer to the date "2001-01-01". I refer to that day, but if I don't have a central factory, many different objects are created for the same day. And it looks like that the concept of "instant in time" can be thought as an entity.  

I currently have ~8000 distinct DateTimes stored, with a total of ~250000 of them. A problem arises, for instance, when loading all those values: it's slower than it could be loading 8000 rows instead of 250000 (and I have 250000 in memory objects instead of 8000)

Comment: Are you really sure it's significantly slower though? Have you benchmarked both options? The purpose of elements like you are using today is that you don't have to worry about entity lifecycle decisions with non-entities. Sure, you could treat "instant in time" as an entity and create a table that holds every possible instant in time. But why would you want to do this? What value does the datetime have outside of the entity here? I doubt you are trying to build an "instant in time" database.